# How use const array with struct C#

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I need to use an array inside the C# struct. my part of the code is as follows,

This is how I defined Struct.

```
struct customerParameter
{
    public const string value1 = "zero";
    public const string value2 = "one";
    public const string value3 = "theree";
    public const string[] multivalues = { "india", "china", "japan" };
}
```

But above code makes a compile-time errors,

```
The expression being assigned to 'customerParameter.multivalues' must be constant.
```

I added the above array in a struct, I need to do the following sample code thing. I need to check if the array consists of the `customerInput` or not. What is the best way to handle this? how can I use Struct with Array to do this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var customerInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (customerInput == customerParameter.value1)
    {
       //do something
    }
    if (customerParameter.multivalues.Contains(customerInput))
    {
        //my code
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: if `customerParameter` is nothing more than `const` holder, you can change it into `static class` form `struct`

Comment: Are you going to be passing this struct to unmanaged code using P/Invoke?

Comment: If you are not intending to use this with P/Invoke, you'd be better off making this a `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a constant, In C# `Const` means it can be determined at the compile-time, which is why only very primitive types such as `string`, `int` and `bool` can be a `const`. So You can use `IReadOnlyList`, to represent a read-only collection of elements. [ReadMore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=net-6.0):

```
struct customerParameter
{
    public const string value1 = "zero";
    public const string value2 = "one";
    public const string value3 = "theree";
    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<string> MULTIVALUES = new[] { "india", "china", "japan" };
}
```

Answer (score 6):

IMO use `readonly` and `constuctor` like

```
public readonly string[] multivalues;

public customerParameter()
{
    multivalues = new[] { "india", "china", "japan" };
}
```

**EDIT**

Depending on your final goal and achievement.

If your struct is used as a configuration struct then `static readonly IReadOnlyList<string>` is one way to go.

If your struct is a model with default values, then the constructor way in my answer is the way to go. But that requires C# 10 and a newer version of C#. If you are using an older version of C# then again stick to `static readonly IReadOnlyList<string>` way.

Comment: I tried ur answer, but it makes compile time error. `Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors`

Comment: Hmm I do not have a compilation issue, how did you manage to do it, I am using it in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Parameterless constructors for `struct` types were introduced in C#10

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a constant. However, you can use a static read-only field which is similar:

```
public static readonly string[] multivalues = new []{ "india", "china", "japan" };
```

Comment: Beware, the elements of this array can still be reassigned.

Comment: You probably want `public static readonly IReadOnlyList<string> multivalues = new []{ "india", "china", "japan" };`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Or maybe better yet, using the `ImmutableArray` type.